# Django Rest Framework JWT Refresh Token One Time Use

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm using jwt for authentication and I want refresh tokens allowed, but it seems that the refresh tokens are still valid indefinitely. Is there an implementation that limits the amount of use of the refresh token? I know the field `JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA` can determine the how long the token is valid but that doesn't solve this current issue.

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token


urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^jwt/create/?", obtain_jwt_token, name="jwt-create"),
    url(r"^jwt/refresh/?", refresh_jwt_token, name="jwt-refresh"),
    url(r"^jwt/verify/?", verify_jwt_token, name="jwt-verify"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just configure below statements in **settings.py** file.

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'users.views.custom_jwt.jwt_response_payload_handler',  // This is the file represents token add external values.
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this custom payload handler and how it resolves my issue?

Comment: @Fendz242 you don't need that one,  just use **'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'** and **JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH**

Comment: @Fendz242 custom **payload handler** is only for attach additional data to the token

Comment: But that does not resolve my issue. I want refresh tokens to be a one time use, I already have it enabled with an expiration timedelta.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt). It is also an official JWT plugin suggested by DRF.

If you configure it correctly following its documentation, then the refresh token can only be used once by default.

Comment: Unfortunately,  django-rest-framework-simplejwt has it's own issues. I noticed when password has been changed, it doesn't make previous tokens invalid. rest_framework_jwt has a field `JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY` that I can set that makes previous tokens invalid.

Comment: Yeah, this is no direct revoke url to invalid a token in simplejwt. We would need to design our own function to revoke to remove a specific token.

From the documentation of [the refresh token in django-rest-framework-jwt](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#refresh-token), it seems there is also no official way to limit the number of times because refresh-token can be used repeatedly until the expiration time defined by JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA.

Based on this, limiting JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA to a small amount of time would be a temp choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a viable option because that would create a bad user experience due to frequent logouts.